# Encapsulation and Passing Lists & Constants Through MAPPLY

Tags: r

I'm having issues passing two lists and a constant data frame from a parent function to a sub function in R.

If the data frame is created outside all functions, the function can access the outside data frame ("lookup_frame") and perform the appropriate actions. See Code Block One.

If the data frame is passed as a constant with two lists, the function does not work. See Code Block Two.

If the data frame is created in a parent function, the subfunction cannot access the data frame ("lookup_frame_two"). See Code Block Three.

An approximate code block of what I'm trying to accomplish looks like this:

```
for(i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    result[i] <- function(list_one[i], list_two[i], data_frame)
}
```

Code Block One

```
#runs fine
df_one <- data.frame(a = numeric(3), b = numeric(3))
df_one$a <- c(1:3)
df_one$b <- c(2:4)

lookup_frame <- data.frame(value_one = numeric(3), value_two = character(3))
lookup_frame$value_one <- c(10:12)
lookup_frame$value_two <- c(1:3)

test_function <- function(x,y){
  return_frame <- data.frame(value = numeric(1), lookup_value_one = numeric(1), lookup_value_two = numeric(1))
  random_test <- x^2+y^2
  return_frame$value <- random_test

  if(random_test < 6){
    return_frame$lookup_value_one <- lookup_frame$value_one[1]
    return_frame$lookup_value_two <- lookup_frame$value_two[1]
  }  

  if(random_test >6){
    if(random_test < 14){
      return_frame$lookup_value_one <- lookup_frame$value_one[2]
      return_frame$lookup_value_two <- lookup_frame$value_two[2]
    }
  }

  if(random_test > 14){
    return_frame$lookup_value_one <- lookup_frame$value_one[3]
    return_frame$lookup_value_two <- lookup_frame$value_two[3]
  }
  return(return_frame)
}

test_output <- do.call(rbind, mapply(test_function, df_one$a, df_one$b, SIMPLIFY = FALSE))
View(test_output)
```

Code Block Two

```
#cannot pass the data frame in as a constant when the other two inputs are lists
test_function_two <- function(x, y, z = data.frame()){
  return_frame <- data.frame(value = numeric(1), lookup_value_one = numeric(1), lookup_value_two = numeric(1))
  random_test <- x^2+y^2
  return_frame$value <- random_test

  if(random_test < 6){
    return_frame$lookup_value_one <- z$value_one[1]
    return_frame$lookup_value_two <- z$value_two[1]
  }  

  if(random_test >6){
    if(random_test < 14){
      return_frame$lookup_value_one <- z$value_one[2]
      return_frame$lookup_value_two <- z$value_two[2]
    }
  }

  if(random_test > 14){
    return_frame$lookup_value_one <- z$value_one[3]
    return_frame$lookup_value_two <- z$value_two[3]
  }
  return(return_frame)
}
#does not work
test_output_two <- do.call(rbind, mapply(test_function_two, df_one$a, df_one$b, lookup_frame, SIMPLIFY = FALSE))
```

Code Block Three

```
#cannot access the data frame in the parent function which calls the subfunction
test_function_three <- function(x,y){
  return_frame <- data.frame(value = numeric(1), lookup_value_one = numeric(1), lookup_value_two = numeric(1))
  random_test <- x^2+y^2
  return_frame$value <- random_test

  if(random_test < 6){
    return_frame$lookup_value_one <- lookup_frame_two$value_one[1]
    return_frame$lookup_value_two <- lookup_frame_two$value_two[1]
  }  

  if(random_test >6){
    if(random_test < 14){
      return_frame$lookup_value_one <- lookup_frame_two$value_one[2]
      return_frame$lookup_value_two <- lookup_frame_two$value_two[2]
    }
  }

  if(random_test > 14){
    return_frame$lookup_value_one <- lookup_frame_two$value_one[3]
    return_frame$lookup_value_two <- lookup_frame_two$value_two[3]
  }
  return(return_frame)
}

test_function_four <- function(){
  lookup_frame_two <- data.frame(value_one = numeric(3), value_two = character(3))
  lookup_frame_two$value_one <- c(10:12)
  lookup_frame_two$value_two <- c(1:3)

  test_output_two <- do.call(rbind, mapply(test_function_three, df_one$a, df_one$b, SIMPLIFY = FALSE))
  return(test_output_two)
}
#does not work
test_if_four_works <- test_function_four()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mapply` requires a `list` for the `MoreArgs`parameter.
Code Block Two will work if you change the last line to:

```
test_output_two <- do.call(rbind,mapply(test_function_two, df_one$a, df_one$b, MoreArgs=list(z=lookup_frame),SIMPLIFY = FALSE))
```

The failure on Code BLock Three is expected since the closure of function `test_function_three` does not contain a defenition for `lookup_frame_two`